# Plotting Top 10 Proportions, but getting an error

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-analysis

I'm plotting the proportion of members of an organization who live in a certain cities. There are quite a few cities represented, so I wanted to just plot the top 10.

I have the following code that will display the top 10 cities.

```
# get proportion taken by most common group for derivation
# of tick marks
n_points = member_clean.shape[0]
max_count = member_clean['City'].value_counts().iloc[:10]
max_prop = max_count / n_points
```

However, when I try to plot the data with the following code, I get the error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

```
# generate tick mark locations and names
tick_props = np.arange(0, max_prop, 0.05)
tick_names = ['{:0.2f}'.format(v) for v in tick_props]

# create the plot
base_color = sb.color_palette()[0]
sb.countplot(data = member_clean, x = 'City', color = base_color)
plt.yticks(tick_props * n_points, tick_names)
plt.ylabel('proportion')
```

I'm a little confused as to what is causing the error. I was able to plot the data using the below code, but I'd still like to understand the error and what I can do to fix it.

```
plt.barh(max_prop.index, max_prop, color = 'g')

plt.xlabel('C', fontsize = 14)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('Cties', fontsize = 6)
plt.title('Top 10 Cities', fontsize = 14)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show();
```

Edited: here's the data output of max_prop

```
OKLAHOMA CITY    0.152073
TULSA            0.105429
EDMOND           0.064838
BROKEN ARROW     0.055477
ARDMORE          0.044957
LAWTON           0.036786
NORMAN           0.031658
SHAWNEE          0.030897
ENID             0.026961
YUKON            0.021238
```

Comment: It's a little hard to say without some sample data.

Comment: if `max_prop` is a dataframe/series, the line `tick_props = np.arange(0, max_prop, 0.05)` does not make a lot of sense. Sine you seem to be new around here, consider familiarizing yourself with [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)